Constructing 3000~6000 with 12 numbers
Is there a set A of 12 integers such that any integer n in [3000,6000] can be expressed as a sum of some elements in A?
If A had 13 integers, it is very easy to do so(By taking {1,2,4,...,4096}) and if it had 11 integers the combination of the integers would be less than required. But can we do it with 12?

Are the integers required to be positive?

Not necessary, but I think the 'negative integers used' case would be easier than the other case, so I'll appreciate if you find a proof for just the positive integers.
edit) this comment is based on my guess that there will be no such A.
